# cape-dict cape-ispell problem with language

Tags: ispell

I setup flyspell to use hunspell program (and installed french and english dict with apt cmd). I set ispell-dictionary to

> fr_FR, en_GB, en_US

Set ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic to

> fr_FR,en_GB, en_US

Then writing some french words in a text file (with mistake too) invoking cape-dic or cape-ispell find no completion.  But writing words in english it works.

Even if I do

> M-x ispell-change-dictionary to fr
> it does not change.

My question is : Does cape-dict or cape-ispell works with other dictionaries languages ?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

> In order to change the word list you have to change the variable
> `ispell-complete-word-dict` or `ispell-alternate-dictionary`. For some
> reason this variable is not modified by `ispell-change-dictionary`.

See https://github.com/minad/cape/issues/70